# TemplateSyntaxError jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'home_page'

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have gone through similar questions like this on Stack Overflow and they got this error mostly because of unclosed quotes but mine is different.

I used the `url_for()` in other html files in my projects but as soon as I target "post.html" it throws this error: **TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'home_page'**

Here is my **main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/templates/<nav_page>")
def navigation(nav_page):
    return render_template(f"{nav_page}.html")

@app.route("/template/post")
def blog_post():

    return render_template("post.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

on index.html the `url_for()` works perfectly. see here:

```html
{% include 'header.html' %}

<!-- Page Header-->
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/assets/img/home1-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
    
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
<div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
        <!-- Post preview-->
        <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="{{url_for('blog_post')}}">
                <h2 class="post-title">Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest</h2>
                <h3 class="post-subtitle">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">
                Posted by
                <a href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a> on September 24, 2022
            </p>
        </div>
```

this is **header.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Big and mighty Blog!</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('home_page')}}">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        Menu
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('home_page')}}">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('navigation', nav_page='about')}}">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('navigation', nav_page='contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</html>
```

in the navigation section, the navbar brand and nav-links work perfectly with the `{{url_for(...)}}`

but when I click on a post in **index.html**

```html
<div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
  <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
      <!-- Post preview-->
      <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="{{url_for('blog_post')}}">
          <h2 class="post-title">Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest</h2>
          <h3 class="post-subtitle">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h3>
        </a>
        <p class="post-meta">
          Posted by
          <a href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a> on September 24, 2022
        </p>
      </div>
```

by triggering the `url_for()` function before "*Man must explore...*" it opens **post.html** quite alright but with an odd error.

**TemplateSyntaxError jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'home_page'**

here is **post.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <title>Blog Post</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/assets/favicon.ico" />
  <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Google fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
  <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css)}}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Start Bootstrap</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('home_page')}}">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('navigation', nav_bar='about')}}">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('navigation', nav_bar='contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Page Header-->
  <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('/static/assets/img/post-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
      <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
          <div class="post-heading">
            <h1>Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest</h1>
            <h2 class="subheading">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h2>
            <span class="meta">
                                Posted by
                                <a href="">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                on August 24, 2022
                            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Post Content-->
  <article class="mb-4">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
      <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
          <p>Never in all their history have...</p>
          <p>Science cuts two ways, of course; its products can be used for both good...</p>
          <p>What was most significant about the lunar voyage was not that man set foot on the Moon but that they set eye on the earth.</p>
          <p>A Chinese tale tells of some men sent to...</p>
          <p>For those who have seen the Earth from space, and for the hundreds and perhaps...</p>
          <h2 class="section-heading">The Final Frontier</h2>
          <p>There can be no thought of finishing for ‘aiming for the stars.’ Both figuratively and literally, it is a task to...</p>
          <p>There can be no thought of finishing for ‘aiming for the stars.’ Both figuratively and literally, it is a task to occupy the generations. And no matter how much progress one makes, there is always the thrill of just beginning.</p>
          <blockquote class="blockquote">The dreams of yesterday are the hopes of today and the reality of tomorrow. Science has not yet mastered prophecy. We predict too much for the next year and yet far too little for the next ten.</blockquote>
          <p>Spaceflights cannot be stopped. This is not the work of any one man or even a group of men. It is a historical process which mankind is carrying out in accordance with the natural laws of human development.</p>
          <h2 class="section-heading">Reaching for the Stars</h2>
          <p>As we got further and further away, it [the Earth] diminished in size. Finally it shrank to the size of a marble, the most beautiful you can imagine. That beautiful, warm, living object looked so fragile, so delicate, that if you touched it
            with a finger it would crumble and fall apart. Seeing this has to change a man.</p>
          <a href="#!"><img class="img-fluid" src="static/assets/img/post-sample-image.jpg" alt="..." /></a>
          <span class="caption text-muted">To go places and do things that have never been done before – that’s what living is all about.</span>
          <p>Space, the final frontier. These are the voyages of the Starship Enterprise. Its five-year mission: to explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no man has gone before.</p>
          <p>As I stand out here in the wonders of the unknown at Hadley, I sort of realize there’s a fundamental truth to our nature, Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest.</p>
          <p>
            Placeholder text by
            <a href="http://spaceipsum.com/">Space Ipsum</a> &middot; Images by
            <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasacommons/">NASA on The Commons</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <!-- Footer-->
  {% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Here's the traceback log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\OLUWAPELUMI\Documents\Python codes\Flask Projects\Blog\main.py", line 16, in blog_post
    return render_template("post.html")
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 149, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 138, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 768, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "c:\users\oluwapelumi\documents\python codes\flask projects\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "C:\Users\OLUWAPELUMI\Documents\Python codes\Flask Projects\Blog\templates\post.html", line 31, in template
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="{{url_for('home_page')}}">Home</a></li>
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'home_page'
```

I've spent hours on Google and Stack Overflow but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **post.html**, in the link tag for the stylesheet, I did not close the filename.

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css)}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

apparently, this error is usually due to unclosed quotes. boy was i wrong.